# RecycleView inside BottomSheet overriding scroll property

Tags: android, scroll, android-recyclerview, bottom-sheet

I have one RecyclerView inside Bottom Sheet and I don't want recyclerview to be scrollable inside it. But here I am facing a problem that Bottom Sheet expand and Collapse swipe property interfere with Recyclerview scroll and nothing is happening when I swipe. Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: Did you disable recyclerview's scroll?

Comment: Yaa.. I tried it by  linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(context) {
 @Override
 public boolean canScrollVertically() {
  return false;
 }
};

and I also tried removing onTouch of recyclerview.

Comment: Try disabling with `recyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);`

Comment: Tried with        
mRecyclerView.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
        mRecyclerView.stopNestedScroll();
        mRecyclerView.stopScroll();
        mRecyclerView.clearOnScrollListeners();

but same issue

Comment: if you don't want to scroll recylerview why you are using it. just use linear layout and `addView()` method if rows are dynamic.

Comment: I was following the same way initially. But I have to reuse the same recycler view in another place with scroll property.

Comment: Any progress? Have the same issue